# Mockito don't work MockitoSessionLogger DefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

My tests in Spring project work well until I did something and in my WebMvcTest, MockMvc started simply to be null. In Service tests where I need to mock my repository this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/session/MockitoSessionLogger
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3215)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3420)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2631)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.registerExtension(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.createRegistryFrom(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:123)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ExtensionUtils.populateNewExtensionRegistryFromExtendWithAnnotation(ExtensionUtils.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.session.MockitoSessionLogger
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: You are missing a dependency hence the error. Please add your `pom.xml` as generally these kind of errors come from wrong dependencies in your `pom.xml` or trying to work around the Sprign Boot starters.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to add the `mockito-core` dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `mockito-all` dependency mentioned in another answer was last updated in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, my issue was solved by adding `mockito-core` and also `mockito-junit-jupiter` beside each other in my dependencies:

```
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to check your dependencies, if this [mockito-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5) is including in the test resources.